# How to use principal variation search for checkers game along with negamax?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am developing a checkers game in j2me. Uptill now, I am using Negamax, But its so slow(with alpha-beta cutoff). I was searching Stack and came to know the term"principal variation search". The post had this link: [chessprogramming](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Principal+Variation)

The negamax which I am using is this:

```
 public double Negamax(int[] board, int depth, int turn, double alpha, double beta){
//check for depth, if its zero then call evaluation()
//generate moves
newScore = -Negamax(newBoard, depth - 1, opponent(turn), -beta, -alpha);
//alpha-beta cutoff
}
```

**The problem:**
Puesocode from Wiki is: [pvs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negascout)

Now I am confused how to use pvs. Should I use it inside negamax, Or instead of negamax. Its header is also confusing, as it accepts a node, not the whole chackers board.

```
function pvs(node, depth, α, β)
```

I am not willing to use transposition table, as I am developing a mobile app.
Thanks

Comment: A node *is* the whole checkers board, together with the player information, so it represents the parameters `board` and `turn` in your implementation

Comment: And I should use pvs instead of Negamax, right?